# Programmatic SLI and CrossFireX Detection

Tags: c, opengl, multi-gpu

Using C how can I detect the currently installed discrete GPUs and if they are currently in CrossFireX or SLI. I am using windows 7 and openGL. I would like to discover this information so that in my game I can support [Alternate Frame Rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternate_frame_rendering) more efficiently.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use specific extensions, for each vendor. For CrossFire, you would use [WGL_AMD_gpu_association](https://khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/AMD/WGL_AMD_gpu_association.txt), and specifically `wglGetGPUIDsAMD` and `wglGetGPUInfoAMD` to get information about the different GPUs. For Nvidia SLI, you would use [WGL_NV_gpu_affinity](https://khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/NV/WGL_NV_gpu_affinity.txt), and specifically `wglEnumGpusNV` and `wglEnumGpuDevicesNV` to get information about the different GPUs.

To actually utilize multi-gpu, you will also need to create your contexts with the functions within those two extensions as well.